# Retrieving an SQL statement from an HTML form with the POST method doesn't query the database

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, crud

I'm currently building a simple CRUD application and decided it would be a nice feature to directly query the database from the browser (i.e from an HTML table) and display ('Read') the results from that particular query.

However, I've been doing some reading and it seems this would essentially be an SQL injection and is something to be avoided. Apparently, it is NOT normal practice to ask a user to input an SQL statement.

Despite this, I've been trying to add this feature to experiment with my code but the SQL statement provided by the HTML form is not being executed.

To recap:

My form in index.php asks the user for an SQL statement.

This is then processed by read.php, which retrieves the SQL statement with the superglobal $_POST['submitsql'] ('submitsql' is just the name of the form's submit button) and queries the database with the query() method. It also displays a message with _$_SESSION[''] superglobal.

From index.php: (form where the user inputs SQL statement)

```html
 <form action ="read.php" method ="post">
 
 SQL statement: <input type="text" name="sql_stat">
 <button type= 'submit' name = 'submitsql'>Query</button>
 </form><br>
```

read.php (retrieves SQL statement and queries the database)

```html
<?php
include ('server.php');

 if(!isset($_SESSION)){

  session_start();

 }

if(isset($_POST['submitsql'])){

 $sql = $_POST['sql_stat'];
 $results = $conn->query($sql);
 $conn->close();
 $_SESSION['message'] = "Query successfully sent: ".$sql;
 header('location: index.php');
}else{

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Students` ORDER BY `degree`"; 
 $results = $conn->query($sql);
 $conn->close();


}

?>
```

For some reason, the message containing the SQL statement is correctly displayed but the database is not queried and all the records are shown (in a table in index.php).

I hope I'm making sense here. My code was working fine when read.php was querying the database directly as opposed to retrieving the SQL statement from the HTML form in index.php. Apologies if I'm not expressing myself correctly.

If it makes any difference, here is the entire index.php:

```html
<?php
include('server.php');
include('create.php');
include('read.php');
include('delete.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>CRUD PROJECT</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>CRUD project</h1>

 <h4>Query the database:</h4>
 <form action ="read.php" method ="post">
 
 SQL statement: <input type="text" name="sql_stat">
 <button type= 'submit' name = 'submitsql'>Query</button>
 </form><br>
 
 <?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){

  echo $_SESSION['message'];
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
 
 }

 ?>

  <table border = '1' cellpadding = '10' >
  <tr>
   <th>Student ID</th><th>Degree</th><th>Grade</th><th>Graduation Year</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   
  </tr>

  <?php



  if($results->num_rows>0){

   while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){

    echo "<tr><td>".$row['student_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['degree']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['grade']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['graduation_year']."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href = 'update.php?student_id=".$row['student_id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href = 'delete.php?student_id=".$row['student_id']."'>Delete</a></td>";


   }
  }else {

   echo "NO RESULTS TO DISPLAY";
  }


  ?>
  </table>


 <br>

 <h2> Add new records </h2>
 <form action ="create.php" method ="post">
 
 Degree: <input type="text" name="degree"><br>
 Grade: <input type="text" name="grade"><br>
 Graduation year: <input type="text" name="graduation_year"><br>
 <button type= 'submit' name = 'submit'>Submit</button>
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

And server.php where I connect to the database and initialise my variables:

```html
<?php

//Define connection parameters
$db_server = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_password = 'therasmus1';
$db_name = 'University_records';

$conn = new mysqli($db_server,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

// Toggle error display 

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

// Initialise your variables (optional - good practice)
 $Degree = "";
 $Grade = "";
 $Graduation_year = "";
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Students`";
  $results = $conn->query($sql);

?>
```

All feedback is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is fine for an experiment. **HOWEVER** and this is a massive **HOWEVER**, do not make this a public facing web app if you value your database **and** users. What would happen if someone was to enter `DROP Table Students`? If some one inserts some malicious javascript into a field that is displayed in a browser, you have then potentially compromised you users system.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. This is just for experimentation purposes. I was curious about creating a sort of search bar by using an html form that could feed SQL statements to the database and change the records on display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that there is an issue with your logic. You are submitting your form to `read.php` then preparing the `$results` in that file and then immediately  redirecting to `index.php` so you never use the `$results` when you submit the form.

But you are also including the `read.php` in your `index.php` file. So what happens is that, you submit your form to `read.php`, create the `$results`(but never use it), redirect to `index.php`, in the `index.php` you have included `read.php` so now it checks `if(isset($_POST['submitsql'])){` and since the request method now is not `post` it goes to `else` block:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Students` ORDER BY `degree`"; 
$results = $conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
```

So the `$results` contains all the records of the `Students` table.

With this logic, no matter what you type in `<input type="text" name="sql_stat">`, you will always get the `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Students ORDER BY degree";`

The easiest way to fix this problem, is:

1. Submit your form to `index.php`. In `index.php` Change `<form action="read.php" method="post">` to `<form action="index.php" method="post">`
2. Remove the `header('location: index.php');` from `read.php`

This fix will solve your current problem.

Comment: You are right! I changed the form action to index.php and then placed the if isset statement from read.php to index.php. It works fine now, thanks!